# ms access query joining two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables that need to be output into an un-editable form.  I need the syntax for the query.

```
TableOne has fields id, customer_id, date, type_id.  
TableTwo has fields type_id, type_name.
```

I have:

```
SELECT * FROM TableOne WHERE customer_id=someVariable
```

But it just outputs a number for type_id.  I need it to print out the type_name associated with the type_id instead of printing out the number.  How do I change the syntax of the SQL to get it to do this?

Comment: Joining tables is a very fundamental skill for writing queries.  Since you had to ask this question, I have heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself Sql in 10 Minutes.

Comment: @DanBracuk Can you recommend good free resources on the web?  Stack Overflow is not a place to advertise books, because the person posting the book suggestion may be connected to the author or publisher.  And people find these postings from google searches looking for free answers.

Comment: @CodeMed - Google `sql tutorial`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN

LEFT JOIN will give you all t1 even if you have no corresponding type_id in t2
INNER JOIN will only retrieve results where corresponding type_id exists in t1 and t2.

```
select t1.Id, t1.customer_id, t1.date, t2.type_name
FROM TableOne t1
LEFT JOIN TableTwo t2 on t1.type_id = t2.type_id;
```

Comment: Althaus Thank you.  +1 for a quick response.  And credit for the answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT 
    cus.CustomerID,
    cus.Name,
    cus.Email,
    cus.MobileNo,
    cus.OtherNo,
    bloc.Block,
    flor.FlooerNo,
    flat.FlateNo 
FROM 
    ((Customer cus inner join BuildingBlocks bloc on cus.Block=bloc.BlockId) inner join BuildingFloors flor on cus.Flooler=flor.FlooerID)inner join BuildingFlateNo flat on cus.FlateNo=flat.FlateId 
WHERE
    cus.Isdeleted=false
```

Comment: Could you please properly format you code sample using 4 spaces (see editing help) and also add an explanation on how your recommendation is helpful.