# Generate SQL Query From Two Tables (MS Access)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I have two tables in my in my database

Interim Storage Orders Table

```
|ID|Date Product Was Made|RecipeID|  Recipe Name  |ProductID|Product Name|
 1   November 10th, 2015    1       100LB S Batch    1         Saltbread
 2   November 10th, 2015    2       100LB B Batch    2         Bran Fruit
```

Recipes Table

```
 |RecipeID|   Recipe Name   |ProductID|Product Name|ItemID| Item |Amount
     1       100LB S Batch       1      Saltbread     213   Salt   100
     1       100LB S Batch       1      Saltbread     56    Sugar   60
     2       100LB B Batch       2      Bran Fruit    213   Salt    34
     2       100LB B Batch       2      Bran Fruit    56    Sugar   12
```

What I would like to achieve is a Query Table displaying

```
ItemID | Item |      Date Used      | Amount | ProductID | Product Name |
  213    Salt   November 10th, 2015    100         1         Saltbread
  56     Sugar  November 10th, 2015     60         1         Saltbread
  213    Salt   November 10th, 2015     34         2         Bran Fruit
  56     Sugar  November 10th, 2015     12         2         Bran Fruit
```

what would be the SQL code to achive this result in MS Access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ms access query joining two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121041/ms-access-query-joining-two-tables)

Answer (score 0):

This would be your query:

```
--Iso is Interim Storage Orders Table
--Rec is Recipes Table
--As stated in query

SELECT Rec.ItemID, Rec.Item, Iso.DateProductWasMade, 
Rec.Amount, Iso.ProductID, Iso.ProductName
FROM Recipes AS Rec
INNER JOIN InterimStorageOrders AS Iso ON Rec.ProductID = Iso.ProductID
```

Comment: SELECT Rec.ItemID, Rec.Item, Iso.[Date Product Was Made], 
Rec.Amount, Iso.ProductID, Iso.[Product Name]
FROM Recipes AS Rec
INNER JOIN [Interim Storage Orders] AS Iso ON Rec.ProductID = Iso.ProductID                                                                                                                                                                                                           Thanks for the answer really appreciate it, I just changed the SQL code a little cause it was asking for parameter values